# Using $q, struggling to get rejections to cascade in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a series of promises, on dependant on the other completing and want to "then" them together to get a single promise representing the completion of the whole sequence.  This seems to work fine however I can't seem to get any failures to cascade down the promise chain as it appears they are supposed to do from the documentation, here's a code sample to illustrate what I'm struggling with:

```
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve();

  var resolvedPromise = deferred.promise;
  var rejectedPromise = $q.reject('rejected');

  var aPromise = resolvedPromise.then(rejectedPromise);

  aPromise.then(function () {
    console.log('promise fulfilled');
  }, function () { 
    console.log('promise rejected'); 
  });
```

[The same in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HJFEVDMw9mObRPy0Mwsy)

I would expect "promise rejected" to be logged, but instead I get "promise fulfilled". Any ideas how I can achieve my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't **return** the rejected promise from the success callback of the resolved one:

```
var aPromise = resolvedPromise.then(function() {
    return rejectedPromise;
});
```

Also note that, to construct a resolved promise, you could simply use

```
var resolvedPromise = $q.when('result');
```

Answer (score 11):

JBNizet's answer is good but I think something needs to be clarified.

The `then` function promises have will **ignore** anything passed to it other than a function. So when you have code that does:

```
myPromise.then(otherPromise)
```

The whole `otherPromise` part is completely ignored. The rationale for this that since Promises/A+ does not specify a `catch` method you needed to be able to do `.then(null, errHandler)` to handle errors without changing the promise value itself if it resolved.